# How do you change the font size on a TextButton flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, font-size

here would you change the font size of Hello World in this example?
Tried the font style etc but gets errors, what am I missing pls?

```
new TextButton(
      style: ButtonStyle(
        foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.white.withOpacity(0.7)),
        overlayColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color>(
                (Set<MaterialState> states) {
              if (states.contains(MaterialState.focused) ||
                    states.contains(MaterialState.pressed))
                  return Colors.red.withOpacity(0.7);
                return Colors.red;
              return Colors.white70; // Defer to the widget's default.
            }
        ),
      ),
      child: new Text('Hello World'),
```

Comment: "fontSize" in Text() widget using Text(style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try out

```
TextButton(
            style: ButtonStyle(
              foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(
                  Colors.white.withOpacity(0.7)),
              overlayColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color>(
                  (Set<MaterialState> states) {
                if (states.contains(MaterialState.focused) ||
                    states.contains(MaterialState.pressed))
                  return Colors.red.withOpacity(0.7);
                return Colors.red; // Defer to the widget's default.
              return Colors.white70;
              }),
            ),
            child: new Text('Hello World', style: TextStyle( fontSize: 30),),
          )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SizedBox(

height:100,
width:100,
new TextButton(
      style: ButtonStyle(
        foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.white.withOpacity(0.7)),
        overlayColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color>(
                (Set<MaterialState> states) {
              if (states.contains(MaterialState.focused) ||
                    states.contains(MaterialState.pressed))
                  return Colors.red.withOpacity(0.7);
                return Colors.red;
              return Colors.white70; // Defer to the widget's default.
            }
        ),
      ),
    child: new Text('Hello World', style: TextStyle( fontSize: 30),
```

)
)

Comment: Thanks all! So simple when you know how!